# Is the suffix "-ette" used for referring to a female?

Tags: suffixes

I recently came across the word **scooterette** in an Indian newspaper. I wondered if this is an Indian coinage; a quick search on Google showed me it's almost purely Indian. I could not find a reliable dictionary reference, but [this article](http://www.hindu.com/rp/2008/07/18/stories/2008071850010100.htm) says these scooterettes are scooters manufactured specifically for women.

What is the reason this suffix "-ette" is used to refer to a female? Are there other nouns which become feminine by this addition? Or is this just some neologist's portmanteau of **scooter** and **dudette**?

Comment: I know of at least one other noun: [suffragette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffragette)

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ette), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ette), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ette), [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ette&searchmode=none).

Comment: Adding -ette would not make a "scooter for women" as such -- a "scooterette" would be either a small scooter or a female scooter, if there could ever be one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The -ette suffix is normally applied to women, not objects designed specifically for women. Thus *suffragette*, your *dudette*, *usherette* and the like. The French language uses -ette to feminise names: Paul/Paulette, Claude/Claudette, etc., and the same principle is used to feminise some nouns in English to create a female variant.

By extension it can also mean "small", *cigarette*, *novelette*, Nissan's *Vanette* and so on. These aren't female, or specially for women.

It's not normally used to create a noun like *scooterette* meaning "a scooter for women", although perhaps it's simply a smaller scooter which happens to appeal to women (and not men, so it's ridden exclusively by women).

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing to me – after all, the suffix *is* applied to objects as well as women, isn't it?  *Luncheonette, diskette, towelette, launderette*... Just curious; maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @J.R. I know what I meant: I'm not sure the edit makes it any better...

Comment: I see what you're getting at now – thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

There are also *majorette* and *usherette*, but *-ette* can be a diminutive suffix, used to produce words such as *kitchenette* and *cigarette*. It is also sometimes used to describe imitation material such as *leatherette*.

Answer (score 2):

its generally female because of its etymology:
From the French -ette, the feminine form of the diminutive suffix -et.

Answer (score 1):

-ette is frequently used to indicate the fairer sex. As in *bachelorette*, *suffragette*, etc.

> [-ette](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ette)
>   a noun suffix occurring originally in loanwords from French, where it has been used in a variety of diminutive and hypocoristic formations (*brunette; cigarette; coquette; etiquette; rosette*); as an English suffix, *-ette* forms diminutives (*kitchenette; novelette; sermonette*), distinctively feminine nouns (*majorette; usherette*), and names of imitation products (*leatherette*).

Comment: Or even [farmerette](http://www.wordnik.com/words/farmerette)...

Answer (score 1):

Mostly ditto Andrew Leach and Kevin.

Note that -ess is also used in English to make a word feminine, like prince/princess, actor/actress, waiter/waitress, etc.

As the right-wing traditionalist here, I am disappointed to have to add that the use of -ette and -ess to make words feminine is largely dying out. In some cases the male form is now being applied to both sexes, or a new word is chosen to apply to both. Like instead of saying "steward" or "stewardess" we're now supposed to say "flight attendant", etc.

-ette seems to be surviving in the sense of "smaller".

On a tangent, I was in an office supply store a while ago and they had a display of pens. On one side the sign said "Pens for Men" and on the other side "Pens for Women". I didn't have time to look, but I have wondered ever since what the difference would be. Of all the products that might have male and female versions, pens are not one that occurred to me.

Comment: Apparently Bic have launched pens "[for her](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bic+for+her%22)" to general amusement. Pink barrels mean blue ink; purple barrels mean black ink. The reviews on Amazon show what a vital innovation this is.